# VSCode: after upgrade git command failing Host key verification failed

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

After my windows vscode upgrade, my git command stop working and show below log message. my git check out work in command line. not sure what changed during the upgrade.

How to resolve this error message?

```
> git pull
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

[image]

Comment: This is a permission issue. Do you use ssh or https?

Comment: Long after the question was asked, what worked for me was to run "git fetch" in the powershell obtained by running "Terminal: Focus Terminal", not "git fetch" or "ssh git@github.com" or anything else in my WSL prompt. The solution *was* to somehow get the fingerprint approval prompt, but apparently the powershell was using a different known_hosts file somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. delete known_hosts in ~/.ssh
2. genrate or regenerate ssh keys
3. run ssh vs-ssh.visualstudio.com
4. answer yes.